# $uibmodal loading main page not template

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

bootstrap for angular and have this problem with $uibmodal it seems to load whole page not an template here is my code.

```
 $uibModal.open({
    template: [
      '<div class="modal-content">',
      '<div class="modal-header">',
      '<h3 class="modal-title">Regulamin</h3>',
      '</div>',
      '<div class="modal-body">',
      '$1. Give us all your money!',
      '</div>',
      '<div class="modal-footer">',
      '<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="$dismiss()">OK</button>',
      '</div>',
      '</div>'
    ].join(''),
    controller: function ($scope) {

    }
  });
```

all things are imported correcly.

Comment: its working fine with me. Are you getting any error?

Comment: nope just page load into it main page-.- 
http://prntscr.com/eafmx6

Comment: this one opens properly https://pathgather.github.io/popeye/ anguila-ui not;/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm newbie-.- forgot to add ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js

Comment: Accept your own answer to mark the question answered.